# javascript - function only works on second call

Tags: javascript

I have a demo [here](https://codepen.io/ttmt/pen/VwZKqNx)

I have a bar made up of blocks with a marker on top and an input field

Inputting numbers in the input field will slide the marker to that percent

The blocks should change color when the marker is over that block.

This works but the blocks only change color after the marker has moved to another block or the enter is clicked again.

Why doesn't the block change color when the marker moves to that block.

```
const marker = document.querySelector('.bar-marker');
const bars = document.querySelectorAll('.bar-item');
const input = document.querySelector('.value');

(function() {

  input.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      const inputVal = document.querySelector('.value').value;
      moveBar(inputVal)
    }    
  })

  function moveBar(val){
    marker.style.left = val + '%';
    for(let i=0; i<=bars.length; i++){
      bars[i].classList.remove('selected')
      if(marker.offsetLeft > 
        bars[i].offsetLeft && marker.offsetLeft < 
        bars[i].offsetWidth+bars[i].offsetLeft){
        bars[i].classList.add('selected')
      }
    }
  }

})();
```

Comment: Stackoverflow Police

Comment: Yes. I know and used to think this was a Q&A site. Now, you have to study a bunch of policies before dare asking a question. One more minute and your question would have been CLOSED.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

its because you have a `2s animation` transition for the slider which mean `marker.offsetLeft` will have the value of starting point of the slider because of the `2s delay` for reaching its destination. Solution would be to wait for `2s` so that the animation can end and then run the script.

Using `setTimeout` of 2.1s could work.

```
function moveBar(val){
    marker.style.left = val + '%';
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      for(let i=0; i<=bars.length; i++){
        bars[i].classList.remove('selected')
        if(marker.offsetLeft > 
          bars[i].offsetLeft && marker.offsetLeft < 
          bars[i].offsetWidth+bars[i].offsetLeft){
          bars[i].classList.add('selected')
        }
      }
    }, 2100);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I chose to separate the classList.remove and the classList.add, so as soon as the new value is entered, the color bars reset immediately and then change once the marker stops:

```js
const marker = document.querySelector('.bar-marker');
const bars = document.querySelectorAll('.bar-item');
const input = document.querySelector('.value');

(function() {

  input.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      const inputVal = document.querySelector('.value').value;
      moveBar(inputVal)
    }    
  })

  function moveBar(val){
    marker.style.left = val + '%';
    for(let i=0; i<bars.length; i++){
      bars[i].classList.remove('selected')
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
      for (let i=0; i < bars.length; i++) {
        if(marker.offsetLeft > 
          bars[i].offsetLeft && marker.offsetLeft < 
          bars[i].offsetWidth+bars[i].offsetLeft){
          bars[i].classList.add('selected')
        }
      }
    }, 2000)
  }

})();
```